# Javascript used to fill dropdowns works in everything but IE9

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer-9, drop-down-menu

I'm using the following javascript code:

```
function dynamicSelect(id1, id2) {
  if (document.getElementById && document.getElementsByTagName) {
    var sel1 = document.getElementById(id1);
    var sel2 = document.getElementById(id2);
    var clone = sel2.cloneNode(true);
    var clonedOptions = clone.getElementsByTagName("option");
    refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, clonedOptions);
    sel1.onchange = function() {
      refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, clonedOptions);
    };
  }
}

function refreshDynamicSelectOptions(sel1, sel2, clonedOptions) {
  while (sel2.options.length) {
    sel2.remove(0);
  }
  var pattern1 = /( |^)(select)( |$)/;
  var pattern2 = new RegExp("( |^)(" +
  sel1.options[sel1.selectedIndex].value + ")( |$)");
  for (var i = 0; i < clonedOptions.length; i++) {
    if (clonedOptions[i].className.match(pattern1) || clonedOptions[i].className.match(pattern2)) {
      sel2.appendChild(clonedOptions[i].cloneNode(true));
    }
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  dynamicSelect("worktype", "function");
  dynamicSelect("worktype2", "function2");
}
```

And this HTML code:

```
<select class="dropdown" name="type" id="worktype2">
  <option class="select" value="select">Select Type...</option>
  <option value="clerk">White collar</option>
  <option value="worker">Blue collar</option>
</select><br /><br />

<label for="function" class="search-label">SELECT A FUNCTION</label><br />
<select name="function" class="dropdown" id="function2">
<option class="select" value="select">Select Function...</option>
<?php

  $getFunctionsSQL = "SELECT * FROM categories;";
  $getFunctionsSQLresult = mysql_query($getFunctionsSQL) or die(mysql_error()); 
  while ($record = mysql_fetch_array($getFunctionsSQLresult)) {
    echo "<option class='" . $record['type'] . "' value='". $record['category']."'>". $record['category'] ."</option>";
  }

?>
</select><br /><br />
```

What it does is filling one dropdown depending on what's selected in another dropdown.
It works in Firefox, Chrome, IE7, IE8, ...but not in IE9...

Haven't found out why yet.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the [IE console](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589530(v=vs.85).aspx)? That's the first place to look

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/kXgjK/

Comment: I am: SCRIPT65535: Invalid calling object, on this line: for (var i = 0; i < clonedOptions.length; i++) {

Comment: This sort of DOM manipulation is so much simpler with [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Credit to you for _going through the pain_ however I really do recommend learning a JavaScript library like jQuery that obfuscates these issues.

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
var clonedOptions = clone.getElementsByTagName("option");
```

to

```
var clonedOptions = clone.options;
```

seems to fix it for IE9 and doesn't break IE7, IE8 or Chrome for me.

Credit to http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=229946 which seems to have the source of your script :-)

Comment: Yup, that worked! Thanks alot and yes, I got the script online :)

Comment: Great! Do you want to _accept_ this answer (if it solved your problem)? Having a high _accept_ percentage will show others that it's worth spending time helping you, cheers :-)